# Cheap places to park a car in Barcelona?

Tags: public-transport, budget, automobiles, barcelona

I would like to go to Barcelona by car and I'm looking for cheap ways to park my car for about 6 hours. I have already been to Barcelona and I parked my car for 10 hours of parking of Arc De Triomf and it cost me about 40 €, that was pretty expensive.

Are they some parkings in the suburbs or the area of Barcelona which are close to a metro station and with a reasonable price?

Comment: It's a good question, but can you be a bit more specific about "reasonable"? To me, 10 hours of parking in a major international Western city for €40 seems "reasonable" (or at least expected) - how much cheaper are looking for?

Comment: @AndrewFerrier good point, the price was *normal* for a big city, but expensive from an absolute point of view. To be more specific, I'm looking for the cheapest parking not too far (< 500 meters) from a metro station.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Last time I was in Barcelona I parked next to the Sagrada Familia and spent 15 EUR for 24 hours.](https://parclick.com/parking-barcelona/bsm_sagrada_familia) This is the underground car park at the Sagrada Familia market, which worked perfectly for me.

Otherwise, if this is too expensive for you, [Parkopedia has several options ranging from 12 to 36 EUR for 6 hours](http://www.parkopedia.es/parking/barcelona_spain/?ac=1&country=ES&lat=41.38506389999999&lng=2.1734034999999494). The 12 EUR option is [the AparcaandGo parking at the Sants station](http://www.aparcandgo.com/es/parking-sants-barcelona-estacion-tren):

[image: Parkopedia Barcelona]

From there, you'll be a short metro ride away from the city centre.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is difficult to park in Barcelona, but there are some tips. I would recommend you to visit [how to park in Barcelona](https://www.shbarcelona.com/blog/en/all-you-need-to-know-to-park-in-barcelona/) Very well explained. 
You can park in green or blue areas, where you have to pay per hour, but normally is free if you park from 8:00 pm to 7:00 am, so you can leave the car there and pick it up in the morning.
There are free places but far away from the city center, like Montjuic mountain. But you can take the metro from there. Espanya (red line) or Paral•lel (green line)

Comment: I don't want to rent an apartment. What is the goal of your link? And I'll be in Barcelona in the afternoon, parking won't be free?

Comment: Sorry, it is just the general web. Here it comes the link:  https://www.shbarcelona.com/blog/en/all-you-need-to-know-to-park-in-barcelona/

Comment: Sometimes, it is free for some hours. From 2 to 4 pm. I would recommend to visit www.areaverda.cat (there is an English version)

Comment: Is this your website?

Comment: I don't have any website. It is the city hall's website.

Comment: @CBerry It is not the city hall website. It's the website of a [real estate company](https://www.shbarcelona.com/blog/en/pagina-ejemplo/).